# ID_CAP_IDENTIY_DEVICE is missing in WP8.1 Capabilities

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Why is the Capability ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE is missing in Wp8.1?
Due to this I am not able to get Device ID matching the one i am getting in WP8!

And this in turn is causing lot of issues in App Upgradation!

Now I am using,

```
HardwareToken token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
IBuffer hardwareId = token.Id;
HashAlgorithmProvider hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("MD5");
IBuffer hashed = hasher.HashData(hardwareId);
string DeviceId = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hashed);
return DeviceId ;
```

Previously we used,

```
DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueId);
result = (byte[])uniqueId;
string id = Convert.ToBase64String(result).Replace("=", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("+", "");
return id + "";
```

Please suggest a solution so that we can get similar IDs in both platforms!

All help and suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are developing a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app, it wont support ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE as it can be deployed on any device ie phone, tablet or desktop. So instead you can use the HardwareIndentification class to get device ID

```
private string GetDeviceID()
        {
            HardwareToken token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
            IBuffer hardwareId = token.Id;

            HashAlgorithmProvider hasher = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("MD5");
            IBuffer hashed = hasher.HashData(hardwareId);

            string hashedString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(hashed);
            return hashedString;
        }
```

This may be helpful. [Guidance on using the App Specific Hardware ID (ASHWID) to implement per-device app logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx)

Comment: But why MD5 and not any other algorithm?

Comment: @apoorva because md5 is fast. This is not a password you're trying to protect.

Comment: note that any id that is generated by calculations on hardware setup, means that plugging a usb stick, disabling bluetooth or any hardware related modification will result to a different id. ouch!